# SDLWeb 8.5 and SDL tridion 2013 JavaScript namespaces conflicts

Tags: web8.5

I am working on tridion 2013 sp1 to SDL Web 8.5 upgrades. I`m facing JavaScript and editor configuration **namespace conflict** in RTF customization upgrade into sdl Web8.5.

Please find below Tridion 2013 SP1 JavaScript namespace and  want to know the corresponding JavaScript namespace in sdl web 8.5.

- Tridion.Cme.Command
- Tridion.Cme.FaCommand
- Tridion.Cme.Selection
- Tridion.Cme.TableEditorToolbar
- Tridion.Cme.View
- Tridion.Controls.ItemSelectControl
- Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getInstance
- Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings
- Tridion.Cme.Popups
- Tridion.Cme.Commands.ShortcutUri
- Tridion.Cme.Commands.InsertHyperlink
- Tridion.Cme.Commands.InsertImage

**Looking for recommendation and solutions.**

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'namespace conflict'?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for response, I completed my R & D and get all sdl web8.5 JavaScript namespaces.

- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.CommandBase
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.FormatArea.FACommand
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Selection
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Controls.TableEditorToolbar
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Views.ViewBase
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Controls.ItemSelect
- Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance
- Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Constants.Popups
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Commands.Shortcuts.ShortcutUtil
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Commands.FormatArea.InsertHyperlink
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Commands.FormatArea.InsertImage