# Tridion GUI Custom Extensions Upgrade to 8.5 - finding resources in new locations

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, upgrade

After upgrading our Tridion to 8.5, our custom GUI extensions are no longer working.  The problem seems to be that it is no longer finding some resources in the old namespaces.

Based on a hint from [this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18178/upgrading-custom-gui-extension-editor-commands-to-web8-5) we were able to get the following working

```
<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Browse %>
```

by changing it to

```
<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, Browse %>
```

But this does not work for

```
<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, LinkPopupUrlLabel %>
```

How do we find where a resource like "LinkPopupUrlLabel" has moved?  Is there a document that details the changes?  Or is there a place to look within the folder structure or the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no such document, unfortunately. But chances are you will find a given resource in one of these:

- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Strings
- Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings
- Tridion.Web.Core.Strings

LinkPopupUrlLabel, for example, is in Base.

Comment: Thank you, all the resources I needed turned out to be in one of these locations!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such document which states where have the resources moved. The only thing you can do is use both APIs, analyze their changes and based on that you can see where are things now compared to the previous version. And yes, there are few changes (some classes have been removed, some renamed, some moved).